# datagridview ширина столбцов

Tags: c#, datagridview

На таблице установлен dragdrop, и при попытке изменить ширину столбца ошибка, я новичок в c# и ошибку прячу так try { тут код}  catch{}. Заметил что ширину столбца можно менять пока нету таргета на любой из строк. Идея моя такова, хочу во время попадания курсора на заголовок столбца делать `datagridview.ClearSelection();`. Может есть более правильно решение, но я его не знаю, прошу помочь.

Comment: Текст ошибки какой? Сейчас ваши попытки выглядят, как изобретение велосипеда...

Comment: индекс за пределами диапозона

Comment: Ширину меняешь мышкой или программно? У меня в проекте все корректно работает.

Comment: Ширину меняю мышкой, сделал костыль короче, если индекс меньше 0 то drag drop copy не включать, так работает.